# Iframe fit to screen

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, blogs

I am trying to integrate [my blog](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-successfully-embed-my-wordpress-blog-into-my-website) into my website via iframe. However, using this method I have to give the height and width in pixels. I want the blog to fit the screen, though. Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: The answer below suggests that I change my CSS. Then what do I do with the "width" and "height" variables in my html? Here is the full html code of the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
 <title>Shiloh Janowick's Blog!</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="pics/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
</head>

<body>

 <iframe width="" height="" src="http://shilohgameblog.wordpress.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

I left the width and height unspecified because I have no idea what to put in them afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to get full screen use this code on your css:

```
html, body, div, object, iframe, fieldset { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
border: 0;
```

}

**EDIT**: Including that on your CSS at the end your html code has to be like this:

```
<iframe src="http://shilohgameblog.wordpress.com"></iframe>
```

You need to take off everything else on the HTML code because you already put that on your CSS

Comment: Thank you! One more question. I have several youtube videos embedded into my website. Will they fit to the screen too?

Comment: In youtube its kinda the same but you need an url like this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/l8qrqkZApf0 See how it only uses the word embed and the link from a youtube video at automatically fits on full screen

Answer (score 2):

Try this one .
It works great for me.

```
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    iframe {
        display: block;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0 none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Comment: Why is `max-width` required here?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to make an iFrame the width of the page (so it's responsive) all you need to do is this:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ENTERVIDEOID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I've done this with a YouTube video, but you can do this without interfering with anything else. You can also change the height to 100%.